# echart Radar chart Axis Label

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am wondering how to show labels only on one axis in echarts like this
[some other radar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIvnO.png)

If I do:

```
axisLabel: {
    show: true
}
```

All the labels from all the axis are shown

Or, is it possible to use polar RadialAxis and AngleAxis and show strait lines instead of round ones between axis. Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not supported.

Radar has only one axis.

see: https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/5467#issuecomment-293513560

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround if someone stumbles on my question.
I added text graphic and placed it on chart. Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution would consist of adding the data you want to display into the indicator option, and then slicing the first element of the array and apply the axisLabel option on the first element only.

This is a portion of my workaround:

```
indicator: [
  {
    name: data[0].name,
    max: data[0].max,
    color: "white",
    axisLabel: {
      show: true,
      color: "grey"
    }
  },
  ...data.slice(1).map((elem) => ({
    name: elem.name,
    max: elem.max,
    color: "white"
  }))
]
```

You can find the complete solution [here](https://medium.com/@Yousra.H/single-axis-label-for-radar-charts-c87d8ab18f27)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587